# Formatting the output of a TraceClassVisitor

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Let's say I want to pretty print the bytecode of a method with the asm library.

```
public int get777() { return 777; }
```

through `TraceClassVisitor` will look as

```
  // access flags 0x1
  public get777()I
   L0
    LINENUMBER 21 L0
    SIPUSH 777
    IRETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lsomething/Point; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

Now, the thing is that I only care for

```
    SIPUSH 777
    IRETURN
```

being everything else largely irrelevant to me, so I want to wipe them out.

I've thought of filtering the stuff I don't want by inheriting `TraceMethodVisitor`, but it actually turned out to be a final class (bummer!).

Is there any way of formatting the output of a `TraceClassVisitor`, at all? If not, what would you consider the best approach to filter out the stuff I don't care about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of line numbers and local variables information by passing ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG flag to ClassReader.accept() method.

An alternative approach wiuld be to add a visitor before TraceClassVisitor and TraceMethodVisitor that would swallow events you dont want to see in the output.

Comment: ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG seems to work fine! I was wondering why EmptyVisitor seems to be gone in ASM 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at providing my own [Printer](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/Printer.html) (perhaps extending or delegating to [Textifier](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/Textifier.html)) via the [TraceClassVisitor(ClassVisitor,Printer,PrintWriter)](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor.html#TraceClassVisitor%28org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor,%20org.objectweb.asm.util.Printer,%20java.io.PrintWriter%29) constructor. I haven't tested this approach.

Answer (score 0):

My standard approach: Get the source code, search'n'replace `final class` -> `class`, recompile.

Comment: Compile it without the final, create a new JAR from that. Or rename the class and add it your project.